# Binding to Window from a Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In WPF, I have a Window and a Frame in it that will show some Pages. I want to bind to the Window (its properties and/or its DataContext) from the Page.

This is an example of what I tried:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

This succeeds in the XAML of the Window, but fails in the XAML of the Page. How do I get it to work in the Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have no way to set the Binding successfully in this scenario. All the uses of `ElementName`, `RelativeSource`, `Source` are not helpful. We know the main window can be accessed like this `Application.Current.MainWindow`. However following that approach can only be used when the main window is the only window in the application. Otherwise it's not safe. I think the best solution is implement your own attached property helping setting DataContext for your Page (or any FrameworkElement) to some ancestor specified by a Type. That means we will nearly bridge the DataContext flow as if there was not any cut-off. Here is the detailed implementation:

```
//the main class used in your XAML code
public static class DataContextService {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextFromAncestorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DataContextFromAncestor", typeof(object), typeof(DataContextService), new UIPropertyMetadata(dataContextPropertyChanged));
    public static object GetDataContextFromAncestor(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(DataContextFromAncestorProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDataContextFromAncestor(DependencyObject o, object value)
    {
        o.SetValue(DataContextFromAncestorProperty, value);
    }
    private static void dataContextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var elem = target as FrameworkElement;
        var type = e.NewValue as Type;
        if (type == null || elem == null) return;            
        if (elem.IsLoaded) SetDataContextFromAncestorOfType(elem, type);
        else {                
            elem.Loaded += loadedHandler;
        }                    
    }
    private static void SetDataContextFromAncestorOfType(FrameworkElement elem, Type ancestorType)
    {
        elem.DataContext = elem.FindAncestorOfType(ancestorType);
    }
    private static void loadedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        SetDataContextFromAncestorOfType(elem, GetDataContextFromAncestor(elem) as Type);
        elem.Loaded -= loadedHandler;
    }
}
//a helper class to find the first ancestor of some Type
public static class ElementExtension
{
    public static DependencyObject FindAncestorOfType(this DependencyObject o, Type ancestorType)
    {            
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(ancestorType) || parent.GetType() == ancestorType)
            {
                return parent;
            }
            return FindAncestorOfType(parent, ancestorType);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage in XAML**:

```
//suppose this TextBox is inside your Page
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" 
         local:DataContextService.DataContextFromAncestor="{x:Type Window}"/>
```

Please use `{x:Type}` to specify the Type, don't use simple string (such as should use `{x:Type Window}` not just `Window`). The class implemented above does not support that shorthand conversion.